# Are creatures aware of the effect of Mirror of Life Trapping?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, saving-throw

The [Mirror of Life Trapping](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/mirror-of-life-trapping) can trap creatures in it.

> Any creature other than you that sees its reflection in the activated mirror while within 30 feet of it must succeed on a DC 15 Charisma saving throw or be trapped, along with anything it is wearing or carrying, in one of the mirror’s twelve extradimensional cells.

Does the creature even know it's making a save for something? If it doesn't, then it's likely my players will stand around for a while and I'll call for multiple saves. Otherwise, they'll probably look away very quickly.

Comment: Its not this question, but why do you think they should make multiple saves? I would interpret this as something where you just have to prove that your personality is strong enough against this mirror. Maybe because you like the way the mirror shows your reflection.

Comment: @findusl I'm not sure I have a reason why, but I like the idea that every time you look (or more than once at least) you need to brave yourself. Like looking a some lovecraftian visage and remaining firm. Or like standing in some spell AoE and making saves every round

Answer (score 1):

#### It's up to the DM.

It's up to the DM to decide what the player experiences, and to then relate that experience to the rules for perceiving magical effects. In this case, we have [this rule concerning spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#Targets) from the *Player's Handbook*:

> Unless a spell has a perceptible effect, a creature might not know it was targeted by a spell at all. An effect like crackling lightning is obvious, but a more subtle effect, such as an attempt to read a creature's thoughts, typically goes unnoticed, unless a spell says otherwise.

Obviously this is talking about spells, but it should be obvious that it applies to other magical effects. So it is up to the DM to decide what a player experiences when they look at the mirror. The item description does not say.

Comment: This sounds like the question becomes 'do you actually want to trap a player' because multiple saves is pretty much a guarantee that someone is going to get caught, but noticing the effect is close to a guarantee of the opposite.